# How to change select element's background color when it's selected?

Tags: html, css, select, background, selection

```
text
<select>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
text

::selection {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Run HTML and CSS codes above on http://jsfiddle.net/tc99J. Press command-A to select all stuff. You should see this effect:

[image]

You notice the background color of text "a" isn't yellow. How can I change text "a"'s background color to yellow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want?????

```
select {
background-color: yellow;
}
```

your updated fiddle :: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tc99J/1/)**

Comment: No, it isn't. Thanks.